# "request failed with status code: 401" error when trying to push to remote using git2-rs / libgit2

Tags: git, authentication, rust, push, libgit2

I have a local git repository that is being maintained through [git2-rs](https://github.com/rust-lang/git2-rs), a pretty much one-to-one Rust wrapper around the C library [libgit2](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2). I have managed to stage and commit changes using the library. However, I cannot manage to push changes to the remote repository. When I try to connect to the remote I get an error with the following message:

```
request failed with status code: 401
```

Here is my code:

```rust
let repo: Repository = /* get repository */;
let mut remote = repo.find_remote("origin").unwrap();
// connect returns Err, and so this panics.
remote.connect(Direction::Push).unwrap();
```

I have also tried to pass various credentials, but the same error occurs:

```rust
let mut callbacks = RemoteCallbacks::new();
callbacks.credentials(|str, str_opt, cred_type| {
    Ok(Cred::userpass_plaintext("natanfudge", env!("GITHUB_PASSWORD")).unwrap())
});
remote
    .connect_auth(Direction::Push, Some(callbacks), None)
    .unwrap();
```

```rust
let mut callbacks = RemoteCallbacks::new();
callbacks.credentials(|str, str_opt, cred_type| {
    // This line does not panic, only the connect_auth!
    Ok(Cred::ssh_key_from_agent("natanfudge").expect("Could not get ssh key from ssh agent"))
});
remote
    .connect_auth(Direction::Push, Some(callbacks), None)
    .unwrap();
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I solved the problem. There are 3 things that need to be done for this to work:

- Using `connect_auth` with `credentials` is right.
- You *also* need to specify the same credentials with `remote.push`.
- You must specify the same refspec string that you did in `remote_add_push` in `remote.push`.

So this code works:

```rust
fn create_callbacks<'a>() -> RemoteCallbacks<'a>{
    let mut callbacks = RemoteCallbacks::new();
    &callbacks.credentials(|str, str_opt, cred_type| {
        Cred::userpass_plaintext("your-username",env!("GITHUB_PASSWORD"))
    });
    callbacks
}

fn main() {
    let repo = /* get repository */

    let mut remote = repo.find_remote("origin").unwrap();

    remote.connect_auth(Direction::Push, Some(create_callbacks()), None).unwrap();
    repo.remote_add_push("origin", "refs/heads/<branch-name>:refs/heads/<branch-name>").unwrap();
    let mut push_options = PushOptions::default();
    let mut callbacks = create_callbacks();
    push_options.remote_callbacks(callbacks);

    remote.push(&["refs/heads/<branch-name>:refs/heads/<branch-name>"], Some(&mut push_options)).unwrap();

    std::mem::drop(remote);

    Ok(())
}
```

For debugging, using the `push_update_reference` callback is useful. It will say if there was a problem pushing.

```rust
    let mut push_options = PushOptions::default();
    let mut callbacks = create_callbacks();
    callbacks.push_update_reference(|ref,error|{
       println!("ref = {}, error = {:?}", ref, error);
       Ok(())
    });

    remote.push(&["refs/heads/<branch-name>:refs/heads/<branch-name>"], Some(&mut 
    push_options)).unwrap();
```